# Error when trying to get Instagram Embed page HTML code

Tags: php, html, rest, instagram

I'm trying to get the HTML Code of the Instagram's Embed pages for my API, but it returns me a strange error and I do not know what to do now, because I'm new to PHP. The code works on other websites.

I tried it already on other websites like apple.com and the strange thing is that when I call this function on the 'normal' post page it works, the error only appears when I call it on the '/embed' URL.

**This is my PHP Code:**

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        $filename = $_GET['url'];
        $file = file_get_contents($filename);
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($file);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
        $bodies = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
        assert($bodies->length === 1);
        $body = $bodies->item(0);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $body->children->length; $i++) {
            $body->remove($body->children->item($i));
        }
        $stringbody = $dom->saveHTML($body);
        echo $stringbody;
    }
?>
```

**I call the API like this:**

https://api.com/get-website-body.php?url=http://instagr.am/p/BoLVWplBVFb/embed

My goal is to get the body of the website, like it is when I call this code on the https://apple.com URL for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use direct url to **scrape** the data if you use CURL and its faster than file_get_content. Here is the curl code for different urls and this will **scrape** the body data alone.

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    // $website_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1';
    // $website_url = 'https://apple.com';
    // $website_url = $_GET['url'];
    $website_url = 'http://instagr.am/p/BoLVWplBVFb/embed';
    $curl = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $website_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $website_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0');
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
        
        $json = json_decode($str, true);
        print_r($str); // Just taking tha page as it is

        // Taking body part alone and play as your wish
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($str);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
        $bodies = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
        foreach ($bodies as $key => $value) {
            print_r($value);// You will all content of body here
    }
}
```

NOTE: Here you don't want to use `https://api.com/get-website-body.php?url=....`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But there are two problems: 1st the body gets displayed twice and second thing is I cannot see the post, there's just the message 'Error - Please wait a few minutes before you try again.' - Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I finally fixed the problems, now everything works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dharman Thanks! for info. OP is not sending any credit card / Major details to take care about security issue. OP is just scraping details from some URL/ website. In this case, how `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` will be the security issue. Its better if you explain little more.

Comment: You explain why should they switch it off.